# Formulário com input obrigatório envia POST vazio - Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

O formulário dentro de um modal está enviando o POST mesmo com o input requerido mas não preenchido. O modal está dentro de um arquivo separado da página e é incluído pelo include() do PHP.

Na execução do snippet a validação funciona, se está vazio não envia, mas no site não funciona, o que pode ser?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#modalFormAnunciar').modal('show');
 $("#formCampoUnico").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  parent.location.href='404.php';
 });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="modalFormAnunciar" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h6 class="modal-title">Anunciar Premium</h6>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    
<form role="form" id="formCampoUnico" class="formCampoUnico" name="formCampoUnico">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="razaoSocial" class="font-size-12">Razão Social: <span class="input-required">*</span></label>
   <input name="razaoSocial" id="razaoSocial" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Razão Social do CNPJ" autofocus>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-12 return"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button id="btnSend" type="submit" class="btn btn-black font-size-14">Enviar</button>
  </div>
</form>

            <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada no "inspecionar elemento" e veja se o `required` tá lá.

Comment: @Sam está, e ao clicar no botão submit, aparece a mensagem para preencher o campo, mas o form é enviado mesmo assim.

Comment: Encontrei o erro, havia outro form que pegava apenas o evento click da página, de outra instância, e executava o form acima, mancada minha!